# Sharing model classes in a maven module between apps

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have a webapp with model classes containing Hibernate annotation which defines the database properties (e.g. @Column, @Entity, etc). I'm creating a new app that writes to the same database.

Is it a good idea to put all the model classes into a maven module to be shared between apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct approach in your case. Its both scale able and reusable. Maven dependencies can be used across apps and support versioning as well.

If this is a MVC type of app you are developing, the models at best should be kept separate and share able across modules.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know an easy way to extract classes in all packages named "model" to a separate Maven module? (More description about what I mean can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422121/extract-all-classes-under-in-model-packages-to-a-separate-maven-module)

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer if your satisfied with it.

Comment: Yep of course! I was about to but I just want to leave it open for a bit to see if there are anymore comments on this topic. :)