# Extract all classes under in "model" packages to a separate Maven module

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven module with a src directory that looks like this:

```
src/
  main/
   foo/
     model/
       ModelA.java
   bar/
     model/
       ModelB.java
```

What is the easiest way to extract all classes under in "model" packages into a separate Maven module? (i.e. I want to move ModelA and ModelB into a separate module)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a copy-resources plugin in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-models</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>{code_base}/new-module/src/main/foo/model> <!-- location where models need to be copied -->
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/*/model/*.java</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to keep the structure the same when copying over in the outputDirectory? In your example, everything will be in main/foo/model package. But what if I had want foo/model/ bar/model/ packages as well in my output directory?

Comment: I think you can try with src/main/ in outputDirectory. AFAIK, the entire folder structure from source can be copied this way.