# sharing Java classes between services

Tags: java, gradle, architecture

I am currently trying to break my Spring monolith app into multiple services. I have many entities (@Entity, POJO) that would be used in different services.  Obviously I don't want to copy & paste the common code but it seems very fragile to build a jar file and sharing them between projects.

Here is what I have:

```
core
  -- @Entity classes
  -- POJO

App1 - deployed independently
  -- src
  -- core classes

App2 - deployed independently
  -- src
  -- core classes
```

I am using gradle as my build tool, and it looks like it supports multi-project builds.  But I am not sure if that means my core becomes its own repo that must be downloaded to be included, or if that is built as a jar and included.

Can anyone point me to a good example or tutorial on this?  So far I haven't found a clean way to do this.

Comment: see [project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:project_dependencies)

Comment: That would seem that i need to build my core project and then manually copy the jar to my /lib directory.  What if I had my build publish the jar to a maven repository (such as nexus) and then have my gradle file pull down the proper version at build time?

Comment: No, project dependencies don't need a repository. I'm pretty sure it references class files from the `$buildDir` of the other project rather than the jar too

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422008/sharing-model-classes-in-a-maven-module-between-apps

Answer (score 4):

You should share that JAR just as you would any other 3rd party JAR.

Move it into a separate project that results in a JAR being published to your Maven repository; modify all services that need it to add that JAR as a dependency.

Comment: What if I have a Java service and a NodeJS service - is there a way to have these POJO map between the correct JSON on either stack?